# How to read/extract the calendar entries returned by the GetAsync() in the Live SDK?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-8, calendar, windows-live

I am trying to get all the calendars a user has. The code I am using is:

```
LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient( App.Session );
LiveOperationResult operationResult = await liveClient.GetAsync( "me/calendars" );
dynamic result = operationResult.Result;
```

When looking with the debugger into **result** I can see the calendars (keys and values). However I am having a problem extracting the information from this DynamicDictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue and the code to do it (with some debug messages) is as follows:

```
try
{
    LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient( App.Session );
    LiveOperationResult operationResult = await liveClient.GetAsync( "me/calendars" );
    dynamic result = operationResult.Result;

    List<object> data = null;
    IDictionary<string, object> calendar = null;

    string msg = "Calendar names: ";
    Debug.WriteLine( msg );

    if ( operationResult.Result.ContainsKey( "data" ) )
    {
        data = (List<object>)operationResult.Result[ "data" ];
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < data.Count ; i++ )
        {
            calendar = (IDictionary<string, object>)data[ i ];
            if ( calendar.ContainsKey( "name" ) )
            {
                string Name = (string)calendar[ "name" ];
                string ID   = (string)calendar[ "id" ];
                msg = string.Format( "Name = {0}, ID = {1}", Name, ID );
                Debug.WriteLine( msg );
            }
        }
    }
}
catch ( LiveConnectException exception )
{
    Debug.WriteLine( "Error getting calendar info: " + exception.Message );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a dictionary.  You should be able to do:

```
var item = result[key];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the modified line is like the one below, but similar to your suggestion.


List<object> data = (List<object>)operationResult.Result[ "data" ];